# Pip does not install chromedriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pip, selenium-chromedriver

When I ran "pip install selenium" it finished as a success.
Inside the install location there is a folder named webdriver/chrome but inside there is no sign of chromedriver.exe
Why do I need to install selenium and chromedriver separately to use selenium with python?
Using windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the web driver yourself and specify its location to selenium. It doesn't come installed with selenium because there are various browsers to choose from (chromedriver, edgedriver, safaridriver, etc).

You can also try `pip install webdriver_manager` which installs the drivers for you: https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/